# Forgerock - emb.creatingfamsuffix.failure Error when creating the Default Configuration

Tags: openam, forgerock

I did install AM-5.1.1 and embed it on apache-tomcat-8.5.15 port:9595… looks good. I can start it.

The issue I face is regarding the Configuration Options –> Create Default Configuration.

After entering different passwords for the default OpenAM administrator, and default Policy Agent users, I get the following error:

`emb.creatingfamsuffix.failure, refer to install.log under /Users/myUserName/openam for more information`.

The install.log file didn’t help that much. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed... I had to do with OpenDj which was not installed. Did install and works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message and it was due to the iptables service not allowing the connection. Try turning off the iptables service (if you are running Linux) quickly and trying to run the configurator again. If this solves the problem, turn them back on and add a rule to allow your openam traffic.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that may come across this issue, I received this error because I had XAMPP running. Once I quit XAMPP everything was fine.